# Why is relative entropy negative in this computation?

Tags: mathematical-physics, information-theory

I am running some tests using relative entropy on physical systems in equilibrium, and I am seeing some strange results. I wonder if this is an issue in Mathematica itself, but here goes.

I have two systems, one defined by the potential $U_1 (x) = x^2 - 0.2x$ and another defined by the potential $U_2 (x) = 0.91x^2 -0.18x$, where $x\in (-\infty, \infty)$.

I am calculating the relative entropy $H$ between these two systems, where
$$ H = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p_1(x) \log \frac{p_1 (x)}{p_2 (x)} dx $$

$$ p_i(x) = \frac{\exp (-\beta U_i (x))}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp (-\beta U_i (x)) dx} $$
Given the definition of relative entropy, H has to be strictly non-negative. But when I plug in those quantities for $U_i$, I get H to be negative. This is my mathematica code for it:

[image]

How is this possible? Shouldn't relative entropy be strictly non-negative? Unless there is a mistake in my calculations somewhere?

I would appreciate any advice you have for me!

Comment: You have integrated $p_1 \log p_2/p_1$ in the code you've linked instead of $p_1 \log p_1/p_2$. So you're getting $-H$ as the output, which of course should be $<0$. :)

Comment: BTW in this case, since both $U_1$ and $U_2$ are quadratic, both $p_1$ and $p_2$ are Gaussians. You can explicitly compute the KL divergence using [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7440/kl-divergence-between-two-univariate-gaussians).

Comment: Thank you @stochasticboy321, you are right!